# MPAndroidChart show specified range of XValues even when there is no corresponding YValue?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

The Problem I am having is that I have charts which should always show a fixed range of XValues let's say all 24 hours in a day, but the Chart is only showing XValues up to and starting from the point of the first and last YValue, that is if I have two Y events, let's say 2am and 3pm, instead of showing the whole 24 hours, it will start at 2am and end at 3pm.

I think this has something to do with the new way to handle XValues via IAxisValueFormatter, since this used to work fine when we could add both X and Y values to a ChartData.

One hack to workaround this I found is to add empty YValues to first and last hour in my case 0 values, but this brings another issue that no matter what I set the minimum in LeftAxis it starts showing negative label values (starts in -15 instead of 0).

Is there an official way to do this? I have researched quite a bit about this and I am thinking on going back to a previous version of the library where I could just use the old way.

Edit: Just to clarify the problem doesn't have anything to do with the labels, but with the start and end of the Chart in X, it is discarding the range of X which doesn't have any YValues which I understand makes sense but it makes the results look ugly in certain cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setLabelCount()` method to force the axis to draw labels according to the count you specify

According to the documentation:

**`setLabelCount(int count, boolean force)`**

**@param `count`**: the number of y-axis labels that should be displayed

**@param `force`** if enabled, the set label count will be forced, meaning that the exact specified count of labels will be drawn and evenly distributed alongside the axis - this might cause labels to have uneven values

And the **`setLabelCount`** method is defined below

```
public void setLabelCount(int count) {

    if (count > 25)
        count = 25;
    if (count < 2)
        count = 2;

    mLabelCount = count;
    mForceLabels = false;
}
```

You can use **`setLabelCount()`** with **`setAxisMaximum()`** and **`setAxisMinimum()`**

*For example:*

```
axis.setLabelCount(24, true);
axis.setAxisMaximum(24f);
axis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
```

This will draw values from 0 - 24 regardless of Y-Axis values

Comment: I am using the IAxisValueFormatter already, that part is working, however forcing the amount of labels doesn't work for what I try to do, I want to have 24 hours in X, but only show 6 labels to avoid it looking too overcrowded, regardless if I try to force 24 labels for example I still get the problem of Xvalues starting and ending on the first and last YValue.

Comment: You can use `setLabelCount()` along with `setAxisMaximum()` and `setAxisMinimum()`. This will draw all the values according to the count you specify in `setLabelCount()` starting from min value to max value